# How to put a color in html textbox with a condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid-asp.net

Hello guys how to change a color of a textbox in cshtml?. I have this code

```
$("#BUTTON").click(function (event) {
    var urlPA = URL;
    var crty = $("#Courtesy").val();
    var fname = $("#Familyname").val();
    var gname = $("#GivenName").val();

    if (crty != 0 && fname != 0 && gname != 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: urlPA,

            data: 'DATA',
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            /// when success the color of the textbox return to normal
            },
            datatype: "text"
        });
    } else { alert("Please fill up the required fields.");
     ////// when error the textbox background makes red

}
});
```

How to do it?. Thanks.

Comment: @GiladGreen Its different. I have a condition when if the textbox will change the color or not. See code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function to set an inline style:

```
if (crty != 0 && fname != 0 && gname != 0) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlPA,

        data: 'DATA',
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
            /// when success the color of the textbox return to normal
            $('#Courtesy').css('background-color', 'white');
            // add other fields
        },
        datatype: "text"
    });
} else { alert("Please fill up the required fields.");
    ////// when error the textbox background makes red
    $('#Courtesy').css('background-color', 'red');
    // add other fields
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I Figure out my mistake now. Its working fine. +1